# How to obtain the original colors of an image after segmentation in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I am wondering if there is any way to get back the original colors for an image in MATLAB? `color.bmp` is a color image and after operations such as segmentation and setting few pixels to **0** just to delete them from my image, I'd like to "color" the rest of figures back with their original colors. I do know the original RGB values from the original image. The original picture looks  like pic [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8S2o.png). Then i leave only the yellow letters

```
i = imread('zestaw3_12.bmp'); 
o1 = im2double(i); 
% obliczanie kolorów
r = 224/255;
g = 220/255;
b = 51/255;

t = 0.1; 
sr = o1(:,:,1) < r + t & o1(:,:,1) > r - t;
sg = o1(:,:,2) < g + t & o1(:,:,2) > g - t;
sb = o1(:,:,3) < b + t & o1(:,:,3) > b - t;
segm = sr & sg & sb; 
se2 = [0 1 0 ; 1 1 1 ; 0 1 0]; 
segm2 =imopen(segm,se2);
segm3 = imclose(segm2,se2);
```

Here I delete touching frame letters and using **regionprops** function i delete letters I don't want to see any more, and this is the result [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdLhl.png). All i get is **im_ok** logical which is shown at pic [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdLhl.png). And finally I would like to color those F, D and E letters back to yellow as it was in original pic.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have the original image, first load it into MATLAB then use masking to set the pixels that are equal to 0 with whatever the corresponding locations are in the original image.  Assuming the original image is stored in `original.bmp` and the segmented image is stored in `color.bmp`, simply do this:

```
im_orig = imread('original.bmp');
im = imread('color.bmp');
mask = all(im == 0, 3);
im(mask) = im_orig(mask);
```

The first two statements load the two images into the MATLAB workspace. The key statement is the second last one.  It finds a logical mask where any locations in the segmented image where the channels are all 0 for each red, green, blue (i.e. `RGB = (0,0,0)`), these locations are set to `true` while the rest are set to `false`.  The function [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) helps us here where we ensure that all channel values are equal to 0 for each spatial location in the image.

We then use this mask to directly index into the segmented image and copy over the colour pixels from the original image from the locations that were set to black in the segmented image.

Comment: Thank You for an answer, but maybe I'm doing something wrong but it does not work for me.. In original.bmp there are letters with different colours. All i need to do is to delete all non-yellow from this picture and i use segmentation here. Then i need to remove some of them and use **regionprops** function to do it.  After this operation i receive **im_all** as a logical and I'd like to color it back to yellow. I though about making another **sth.bmp** file, fill it with this color I want to get and then just mutiply my **im_all** after conversion to double but it sound pretty lame...

Comment: Please show me (1) The code you wrote. (2) The images themselves. It was very difficult to determine what you were actually doing from your post.  Now from what I understand, what you **really** want is actually not what you're asking in your original question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: OK that's **completely** different than what you've asked.  You basically want to find the original colours of an image given a mask.  I'm marking as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank You very much, it works :)